# Error: Authentication method waterlock-local-auth could not be found.

Tags: npm, sails.js, waterlock

I keep getting this error when trying `sails lift` even after manually running `npm install waterlock-local-auth` again and again

```
info: Starting app...

/backend-api/node_modules/waterlock/lib/methods.js:112
      throw error;
            ^
Error: Authentication method waterlock-local-auth could not be found. 
Try running npm install waterlock-local-auth


    at Object._errorHandler (/backend-api/node_modules/waterlock/lib/methods.js:109:19)
    at Object._handleObjects (/backend-api/node_modules/waterlock/lib/methods.js:54:14)
    at Object.collect (/backend-api/node_modules/waterlock/lib/methods.js:33:19)
    at new Waterlock (/backend-api/node_modules/waterlock/lib/waterlock.js:19:50)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/backend-api/node_modules/waterlock/lib/index.js:8:22)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/backend-api/node_modules/waterlock/index.js:6:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
```

Answer (score 0):

It ended up being `bcrypt` I changed the version number to `1.8.3` instead of `1.8.1`

https://github.com/waterlock/waterlock-local-auth/pull/36

Comment: Where do I change the version of this? package.json in root of Sails project doesn't even show "bcrypt" under dependencies. Is there a different package.json file that needs to be changed? I cannot find it anywhere.

Comment: I think it's a dependency of another dependency. I think I put it in package.json and it overrode the other one.

Answer (score 0):

For

> Error: Authentication method waterlock-local-auth could not be found.

Try running `npm install waterlock-local-auth`